# Make global check function with discord.py-rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, using [`discord.py-rewrite`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I know that I can use:

```py
def check(message):
    """Checks the message author and channel."""
    return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel
await bot.wait_for("message", timeout=180, check=check)
```

to check message input (which must be from the context author and in the context channel). But because I need this check for several commands, can't I just make:

```py
def check_msg(context, message):
    return context.author == message.author and context.channel == message.channel
```

and then use:

```py
await bot.wait_for("message", timeout=180, check=check_msg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rewrite branch of discord.py doesn't exist anymore. It's simply v1 now.

[`Bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)'s `check` predicate to check what to wait for only gets passed the parameters of the event being waited for. This means that since you're waiting for a message event, it'll only be passed the single message argument.

One way to accomplish what you want would be to use a wrapper method that handles the `context` parameter and returns the check predicate, e.g.:

```py
def wrapper(context):
    def check_msg(message):
        return context.author == message.author and context.channel == message.channel
    return check_msg

await bot.wait_for("message", timeout=180, check=wrapper(ctx))
```

Comment: Okay I see, I won't be able to use the `@` syntax then. But it works, thank you!

Comment: Mentions shouldn't really have anything to do with it, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: No I was talking about the `@` syntax for decorators.

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with using the commands extension or not either.